# Can't find a codec for class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

here is my code

```
Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.andOperator(Criteria.where("country").is(country),
            Criteria.where("createTime").lte(wp),
            Criteria.where("location").withinSphere(circle),
            Criteria.where("titleContent").exists(true));

    AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(c);
    AggregationOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(20);
    AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createTime"));
    AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("titleContent").sum("count").as("titleCount").count().as("contentCount");
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, sort, limit, group);
    AggregationResults<TitleRes> result = template.aggregate(aggregation, "post", TitleRes.class);
```

when I add `Criteria.where("location").withinSphere(circle)`

It will throw exception

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand
```

When I remove `Criteria.where("location").withinSphere(circle)`

It is ok.

I do not know how to do with it.I want to get the data withinSphere.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by using geoNear command:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/

Remove location from criteria and use geoNear instead of match:

```
        NearQuery near = NearQuery.near(new GeoJsonPoint(request.getLongitude(), request.getLatitude()));
        near = near.maxDistance(request.getDistance() / Metrics.MILES.getMultiplier());
        near = near.num(2000000);//watch out for max num default restriction
        near = near.spherical(true);
        Query q = new Query();
        q.addCriteria(matchCriteria);
        near = near.query(q);
        AggregationOperation geoNear = Aggregation.geoNear(near, "location");
```